# Android - Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() - Socket.IO

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I am attempting to connect to a SocketIO Web Socket using the socket.io-java-client. This is supposed to support Android yet for an unknown reason I keep getting the following error:

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

If you are familiar with the SocketIO Java client then this error is thrown in the onConnect method on IOConnection. If you are not familiar then here is the code:

```
try {
  if (firstSocket != null && "".equals(message.getEndpoint())) {
    setState(STATE_READY);
    if (firstSocket.getNamespace().equals("")) {
      firstSocket.getCallback().onConnect();
    } else {
      IOMessage connect = new IOMessage(
          IOMessage.TYPE_CONNECT,
          firstSocket.getNamespace(), "");
      sendPlain(connect.toString());
    }
    // should flush after connecting to namespace
    flushBuffer();
  } else {
    findCallback(message).onConnect();
  }
  firstSocket = null;
} catch (Exception e) {
  error(new SocketIOException(
      "Exception was thrown in onConnect()", e));
}
```

Comment: this kind of error is explained in zillions threads on SO

Comment: @pskink care to link to the thread as I have searched for 3 nights now to try and find anything to resolve this.

Comment: see "Related" on the right side of this page

Comment: @pskink hmmm that is strange. Cant find any that are related to my issue. I am not updating anything to do with the UI from within the Thread

Comment: post the stack trace then

Comment: @pskink I am debugging my android device and there is no stack trace on the error.

Comment: Post your Thread implementation please

Comment: @ben75 not a duplicate as I am not setting any part of the UI from the Thread.

Comment: @pskink Here you go: [Stack Trace Dump](http://imgur.com/JD3PJEZ.png)

Comment: i dont see any Handler related  code in the stack trace, the error you mention comes from Handler constructor

Comment: what's the code in `onConnect()` ? (i.e in the callback)

Comment: Ok found the problem thanks to @ben75's comment. Even though I specify the code in the UI Thread it is executed in another non-ui thread. Thanks very much. Damn wasted about 10 hours on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either instantiate the `Handler` object on the main UI thread (not inside the background thread), or instantiate it using the following constructor:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have already implemented this. This is the way I found to do it.